# Use getselection as selector?

Tags: jquery, text, jquery-selectors, getselection

How can the text in `getselection();` used as a selector in jquery.

some like this but this doesn't wok:

```
var sel = window.getselection();
$(sel).wrap('<div class=\"onetwothree\"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The .wrap purpose it to wrap the selected items in jQuery with something.
As sel is a selection of text and not a valid jQuery selector you could do following:

First you find the selection of text which the user got.
Then you find the container of that text and get the html of it.
After that's done you could split the string using the split function into an array with 2 indexed. The split string should be the selection. Then you got what's on the left side of the selection and what's on the right.

Now you can combine that array with what you wan't to wrap us, for an example:

```
var splittedContent = ['leftside', 'rightside'];

var newStr = splittedContent[0]+'<div class="somediv">'+yourSelection+'</div>'+splittedContent[1];

$('.container').html(newStr);
```

This would take what's on the left side and combine it with a wrapping div around the selection and then drop the rightside of the selection at the end. then afterwards it will then set the html back to the element which we took the html from

Hope this gave you the lead to continue :)